# Make spring `login` filter available via GET

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

We are using spring security version 4.2.3,

I want to configure that the `login` filter be available via `GET`. (By default calling `http://127.0.0.1/login` with `GET` http method returns `404`. )

To do this I extend the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` to configure my own filter and configure it as below

```
<beans:bean id="myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
            class="foo.bar.MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
            <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
            <beans:property name="postOnly" value="false"/>
</beans:bean>
```

and also

```
<http entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"/>
    ......
```

It is not working!

During debug I find that there is a hard coded line at `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` constructor which is as below:

```
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
    }
```

I *think*, this cause that the `AntPathRequestMatcher.matches` always return `false`

Well can I configure the `login` filter to be available via `GET`. So calling `http://127.0.0.1/login/username=foo&bar=bar` will be processed?! how ?

Comment: @dur it worked! Calling the `setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher( new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login","GET") );` in `myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` constructor solved the issue. Please send it as answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`postOnly`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html#setPostOnly-boolean-):

> Defines whether only HTTP POST requests will be allowed by this filter. If set to true, and an authentication request is received which is not a POST request, an exception will be raised immediately and authentication will not be attempted. The `unsuccessfulAuthentication()` method will be called as if handling a failed authentication.

and [`setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html#setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher-org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher-), see [`AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html):

> This filter will intercept a request and attempt to perform authentication from that request if the request matches the `setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(RequestMatcher)`.

with a [`RequestMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RequestMatcher.html) that matches HTTP `GET`. For example:

```
new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "GET")
```

see [`AntPathRequestMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher.html#AntPathRequestMatcher-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

> Creates a matcher with the supplied pattern and HTTP method in a case insensitive manner.